# Gatsby build failed. Can't build "Sharp"

Tags: node.js, node-modules, gatsby, sharp, javascript-build

I tried everything.

1. Removed `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`
2. Downgraded sharp-plugins
3. apt installed libvips && libvips-dev
4. $ npm install -g node-gyp

Before installing libvips-dev. The build error was caused because libvips wasn't found. Now after apt-get installing libvips-dev, glib-object is not found. I don't know what to do.

Here is the useful bit of the error message:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/me/Desktop/project/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
In file included from ../src/common.cc:25:
/usr/include/vips/vips8:35:10: fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib-object.h>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there was a "bad" version of sharp cached by npm.

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8852#issuecomment-427641767

This fixed it:

```
rm  /home/me/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8*
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and other `rm` doesn't work for me.

May be because I use `nvm`. I remove the node under nvm, (`~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/`) and reinstall node version, and package `node-gyp`, `node-pre-gyp`.

It works.